# Appending data to model always empty Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, model, codable

I am trying to append data on model after based on selections. Data is based on cell index selection but for some reasons its not appending to model. Data values are here may be I am doing something wrong in appending data . 
I am using delegate after append data and to pass model to previous viewController.

- I need to append data in `Item - selection` - see model

Data appending declaration `var dataItems: [Item]?`

Model:

```
struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?
}

struct Item : Codable {

    var textField : String?
    var textValue : String?
    var pickList: [SectionList]?
    var selection: [Item]?
    var multiSelect: Bool?
    var masterId: Int?
    var itemValue: String?

}
```

Main function for appending then delegate: 
here **dataItems are not appending** values here on `selectedItem`

```
if let selectedItem = AppData?.pickList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row] {
  dataItems?.append(selectedItem)
}


@IBAction func bittiBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        print(dataValue)
        pickDelegate?.listPick(listValue: dataValue, selectedItems: dataItems ?? [])
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Values I am getting which needs to be append at `dataItems: [Item]?`

```
▿ Item
  ▿ textField : Optional<String>
    - some : "Tipi ve kesiti uygun olmalı"
  - textValue : nil
  - pickList : nil
  - selection : nil
  - multiSelect : nil
  ▿ masterId : Optional<Int>
    - some : 671
  ▿ itemValue : Optional<String>
    - some : "347"
```

Comment: where are you declaring dataitems ?

Comment: you havent inialize your dataitems array .... thats why its not appending

Comment: @jawadAli its intializer where variable declares just after class name.

Comment: can you show that code too ?

Comment: actually code is quite lengthy. But I have used this on the top `var dataItems: [Item]?`

Comment: That declares it but it doesn't initialise it. You need something like `var dataItems = [Item]()`

Comment: @Paulw11  Yes you are right. Let me implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise your `dataItems` array

```
var dataItems = [Item]()
```

and if you still want it to be optional you can do

```
var dataItems:[Item]? = [Item]()
```